# Facebook blank page after login Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
                    $.getScript('https://connect.facebook.net/en_UK/all.js', function() {

                        FB.init({ appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxx', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
                        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response){
                            if(response.status==='connected')
                            {
                                load(response);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                FB.login(function(response) {
                                    if (response.authResponse) {
                                      $(".load").html('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                                      FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                                        $(".load").html('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
                                        load(response);
                                      });
                                    } else {
                                      $(".load").html('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });

                });    
            });
```

The Login dialog popups correctly, but after login it goes to a blank page https://www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2FDU1Ia251o0y.js%3Fversion%3D41%23cb%3Df246e4d89fef184%26domain%3Dlocalhost%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Ffeb48fe70fe9c%26relation%3Dopener%26frame%3Df1092c4e4c168ce&display=popup&response_type=token%2Csigned_request&domain=localhost&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxx&ret=login&sdk=joey&ext=1424366134&hash=AeaJ_v2XTa9paggktPU

It does not close, i am working on a localhost and using Mozilla Firefox.

**Things i noted:**

1. User is logged in.
2. If popup closed then it `does` call back function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It successfully worked on after clearing the cache and cookies of my browser.